# Function Plot / how to use the library

Tags: javascript

I have not been using JS/HTML for a long time. I see it changed a lot over time. I tried to use example plotting library from: https://mauriciopoppe.github.io/function-plot/. The code I tried to run in `index.htm` looks like this:

```
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/d3@3/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/function-plot@1/dist/function-plot.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    import d3 from "d3";
    window.d3 = d3;

    const functionPlot = require("function-plot");
    const root = document.querySelector("#root");

    functionPlot({
      target: '#quadratic',
      data: [{
        fn: 'x^2'
      }]
    })
</script>
```

However, Chrome screams on console log the following message and nothing shows:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "d3".
>   Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use import or require statements for global reference, Once you add a script in the HTML, it will become a global reference. So you can directly access them by name `functionPlot` or `window.functionPlot`.

And there is no element has `quadratic` as Id.

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/function-plot@1.22.2/dist/function-plot.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    functionPlot({
        target: '#root',
        data: [{ fn: 'x^2' }]
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I found a working example. The issue was with included scripts presented on official page. Sharing code for others:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://mauriciopoppe.github.io/function-plot/js/function-plot.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    functionPlot({
        target: '#root',
        data: [{
            fn: 'sin(x)'
        }],
        grid: true,
        yAxis: {domain: [-1, 1]},
        xAxis: {domain: [0, 2*Math.PI]}
    });
</script>
```

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU, THANK YOU. It's unbelievable how hard it is to find information on actually implementing a working example of a graph made with this library.